# Switch front/back camera on Android while on WebRTC call using Circuit SDK

Tags: circuit-sdk

I am able to make a direct call between a Circuit WebClient and the example SDK app at https://output.jsbin.com/posoko.

When running the SDK example on a PC with a second camera (USB), the switching between the built-in camera and the USB camera works fine. But trying the same on my Android device (Samsung Galaxy S6) the switching does not work.

My code uses `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to get the cameras and then uses the Circuit SDK function `setMediaDevices` to switch to the other camera.

```
async function switchCam() {
  let availDevices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  availDevices = availDevices.filter(si => si.kind === 'videoinput');
  let newDevice = availDevices[1]; // secondary camera
  await client.setMediaDevices({video: newDevice.deviceId})
}
```

Can somebody explain why this doesn’t work on an Android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have seen Android devices that don't allow calling `navigator.getUserMedia` while a video track (and therefore a stream) is still active. I tried your example above with a Pixel 2 without any issues though.

If you remove the video track from the stream and stop the track before calling [client.setMediaDevices](https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_setMediaDevices), the switch should work.

```
async function switchCam() {
  const stream = await client.getLocalAudioVideoStream();
  const currTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
  console.log(`Remove and stop current track: ${currTrack.label}`);

  stream.removeTrack(currTrack);
  currTrack.stop();

  let availDevices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  availDevices = availDevices.filter(si => si.kind === 'videoinput');
  let newDevice = availDevices[1]; // secondary camera
  await client.setMediaDevices({video: newDevice.deviceId}) 
}
```

There is a complete switch camera example on JSBin at https://output.jsbin.com/wuniwec/

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the hint. I'll accept your answer, but it would be nice to document this workaround in https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_setMediaDevices, so other Android users can quickly fix it.

Comment: Glad it works. Yes, we are going to add that information to the [client.setMediaDevices](https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_setMediaDevices) API.